# getting error messages in wordpress white screen of death

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the wordpress white screen of death.

I want to display error messages. I tried `define('WP_DEBUG', true)` However it does not display any error messages.

Is there  a work around?

Comment: Have you looked in your webserver's error logs? If hosted, look in your host's control panel for logs. If on a local or self-managed Linux, look in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: The Cpanel error logs do not have any error related to the sub domain which shows the white screen of death. Any other work around?

Comment: Start renaming plugin folders (e.g. add X to the end of each folder's name) which will stop them being found by WordPress. Do it one by one, check to see if white screen of death stops. Can you access the admin area (e.g. just add /wp-admin to site's url)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocomerce checkout page internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854995/woocomerce-checkout-page-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 1):

put in **ob_start();** in wp-config.php on top

Answer (score 0):

The general approach that fixed it.

1. Rename your wp-content
2. Activate/ Decactivate your plugins
3. Change your themes
4. adding define('WP_DEBUG', true) in the wp-config.php
5. Check the php files. In my case the php files were missing code!