# Wordpress site with encoding error

Tags: wordpress, encoding

Every 48 hours, when I access my Wordpress site, I can't see the layout. Only a lot of strange characters like the code below:

I have to enter in the admin page and the site chages back to normal.

Any ideas? I never saw this before.

```
%1F‹%08%03í½KsÜ¸²0¸¶%23Î%7F€Ë·-©O±žzËR_Y¶úØ–Ú’ûe%3B%14(%12UE‰EÒ%7Cèa·Vßj"f7»Y%7DgfqãNÄ%5D˜ÍÝúOÌÏ™L%24A%16YÅ*•Üîþ¤nKU%40"‘%12‰ÌD%02xúÈpôàÚe¤%1F+¬­‡OûŒ%1A%5B%0F%1F<%1D°€%12½O%3DŸ%05›•7%27ûÚj%05ÒeF%3F%08%5C%7D%08Í‹ÍÊ%2FÚ›mmÇ%19¸40%3B%16«%10Ý±%03fC©ƒ½Mfô%18”‹+ÚtÀ6%2BÏ©mô™eì%7B%26³+ëZ)sâ…X+%05þÒé˜%16%3Bt%03s%60~d†%02Ýn5²À%17%26»t%1D%2FP+.M%23èo%1AìÂÔ™Æ¿T‰i›I-Í×©ÅÈ%26iÖ%04%26Ë´Ï‰Ç¬ÍŠkÚ½%0EÕÏ%2B¤ï±îf%05Û¼%5E¯_%5E%5EÖºÌ2%5DÖñ¨oZ5Ý%19Ô%3A%5Eýj%60y®%5Esû.Ç%13˜Å¶v½%1AÙçÀä%19‡%26%1A9ô%02Çe†é%03É¿“%13†%03%1A8–Ó“)%3B¦%17z%3D“%12ƒ‘%1F%1Cfõ§uíáÃ§4œôMŸøfÀ%08üu¢%5E!—fÐ%27AŸ‘_%1Dê%07äxï¸VØ3mr±%5CkÖšP56Á‡6%5C%3B´æ%07õæuï»0%18œF%1D%25Á4%60%03¥C+æëž+Õ8¶Ò§Q%2B(a+ÅŽ¤¸J¶½Às%7CÝqMZ%25%2FÌ%1E+²%03H%7FÉl%13’«äÈûü¯€ù+Ê%1Fú%01s%02g€È%06d%1F%06%0FÆä%23­‘m¨Ë0yIrD½ÀÔC‹zUòæÕÁË½Ý*ö)Rç%0E%27Äúj•%3A%10ŸŒ¡NmÇ6aˆK%0Eb…Ô£Æ»%1E´Ï+®7%2BNoÝrM”æ»Áé³×EÐ8ŸTöc%1D%1C­Bh%1C%5B%05%7C6ªï•Âb6%040Í%02æ­ëÔS%05‘%1F%0E%06Ô».%04ÿ³v%7Bº%15wÉª¢%7F%08ÎÍ9êº%16L%5Bì®ºeüýÌwì¹­O•%7Fç5_%05•u1èïêïê¾Þg%03Zs¼%5E¥Zùw>õÖ%2B%3F³Î1N9H1+øþ8šƒÕ+òŽR¼€kÞÕ%01”3Çz%0EST%2B®ƒ%3D+È¶ÎÇtýS%5C÷1£žÞ—éÕJ%40½%1E+JUù¿ùÉç¥O¡·%07§~àÁ%1At%03H>„Ì»ÖLÛ+%11“‡%2B¯%07"ŸÎp‰ÊÍÍÓºèÏô8%0Eü+j™%06+X­ÑTÆqgomom»±Û~¶³Ò%5CZ%5BÝ_nî%2C%3FÛk4ÚûKûkÍÆ%10Cô%1C§g1+»T»%60žÙ•ƒ¥à<%1B¬%19ôäòõ+óóòb»õÓà%1FËo¬Cí§ÆîÕó«WÚ2%5BþÇqÏ¹>+ü—%02%3D.mõ¡Å«Æ×%23E¦Ï%19¶¯¹+ÌY+÷ç„XŸ«×ýFíÒÅžœ%23©%25+%08¼Öóè%05…Á)_¦+Mƒr¼éÔ5ýIj»D%06ÍW¨%05ƒfS%5C%1A8ÛWT¶÷%7Cÿï+S%40%16NºÍÊ>ƒ%01w©GÉð¬%7BâÑ%0F¡³Qr‘ë%02%26)%15oC+Ì_%40%08cýùŸžéø³¡+þ+J_%252­ó„>ó¹šó%3D%1F%08²mSë%1A„šO%3A×ä¥cƒ%18ô%0Elßìõ%03_Q€Zµ%15%10No%7C˜%1EJ‘À%03%05%0F“%12Ý%08)%1B%084¦DƒÄÕ‘%0Fÿ–%16S%15”Eõ3à%23‘Z!0µ¨¦w©%7Fmë›•.µ%7CPfÿ%06Úï%05õ%08ÈD+òqà¾9×£šL%40ýyuq­¹¼Ôjjí¹¿%3D„%12õoÉ~hs!B%40p%1B%2C%60z€Ú%1Eô<ˆiì%06Ï%27ßÖ%01´%1BÁžöè+¶%08zÀ%3FDÐÃ0˜_+Ÿ%02%05¡gÃê¢‡ØÃÐ%26çÜd5Ó6ØÕaw%5E!îïdn35%7Cnl%11­+ô<¸‰hÚ%15%60IÇ™%5D>%18%40˜†d+¬„%5D´÷k‚>™%2F¤MRw+t8—o%13*ÞC%1F!%11©Ú%0Fe-q‹+Û%0FNÜv’m5àÎiï%06í‚%5Cõ7Oúa•´›d—é¤ÕX%5B%23­öúÒ%1AüOÞœìl§ƒ9QÇ%02Ôã(%7Fð%60>"pÞ¬úU§Ú«zUZ%1D%2C%7C2ßÎ+%26Ž%19ò°s%06Ã<÷~ÓÛ0ßzï7ñ×ï¿Çå%17x_ÍcjíÃ¦øóûïoß%2FÔÜÐïÏÃJÃ%5Bé%2FÜTy¦µÙüÖf—d%17æõüÂ%06Ý%04Vö%18%7CÙ³%18%02Î%3B+UÄ8€+X¤dªÿìú„ö%5E+‡ü·÷%1B´%26%18º+Ÿ%7COßìm+j0Û%01ô•c+%01%2F%06ÏX×ñØ<6+%1B¾0%2F%3A¦%1Au%7DuNL’¹êœ˜dr+¡QÛù%2CK¾ù©ŒèÜ‚˜%18JÒüœhÍ%5C•Ì¥ç%10%24Ð0p+L¦X³˜+¤êìøø%05%7CÆ¡%1A%02“%2B%2C‚ÂÀº%16½îBE!ðÆ0J%05%16Å©i%24Ÿ°%119%24Ø2çÒ%1EC%5B%15%01âÕúoÑ2XF¸q%04†õH‘„6»œ%5DµÓK—+œ3ó˜%05%01Ì%5D%1F%18õS¥C%7Dö%26Ö‰%7C¡S‰õê%5DÝ%1C•þ%3B%10Ë%1E%7BWç…ßÕ%5Bµö»úJëj¥Åµ%24¡Õ%5C%1B%150ÿ¢7%052(ÅQÁß%3D+>áw%27„qBå+Ô+X‹x™RªÔ¥+Ú’n…%06Vxæó%04%5EZƒÕŽA“k%03Ð-Î%7CP•6°‡%1EÅsŒV%3BU%7DáS%2CT+LYø„%02%5Cß<æúU­ë9ƒ>õv€ý7+RÀè½†‰%3Bß¨6ªç5áb8¯õ%19%0EÔBÕªuMË%3AŽš×k¸®%5EÏ%07°žUé%02€7%166øâ°y%5E+%1C˜¨ôÍë%170W§ÇÚQ°²+Öh%11ØÜÜd7q%13aÖŠ%06v6Ìîü%23ë÷ß%1F%25È%17D™GÍ+%1F¬½%3FoÕÇžA%1F%02“%23Ç9n%05‰qPë%5Bn4H»å%5Eé%02Êq%05šøI%07ÈJ×¢½ÊºD5ßÙ4æß.-µ—–«KË«-ø%1D%7Dn®½¯¦rV%5Bv*%7BaáÉ“%14‚•v»%05yÍÖ*ü%5Elµ“ÏÍU%25½™%7Cn7òá%17W’Ê9VQ¹%02šNü%19ˆf%26%01j%1Aƒ%03ê%5C¨>ê%2Clðn’+.‡)n%25B®¬-bÑ¥ê%1A~Z%5Ej´£®RrÛj.â½‰F%2F%19ín4Úúf%27³%1CT¤Ðj¸+§U½f€2ëmêµ%7CñRíä%2F%1C%15ô%23Vpõ%40Ö%04‰·Ó7-c%5E_¸Áš%7BÕ~Õ¬žUÏ‡)Ð©+È%2BÀÞÀº€zGX%7COž¨ßæ%2B-%40¾%01R%7CþlsÛóèõ¼à°ªìÁ%05+Ü%0F%5Dô%03‚MÅÀD¹†¹a÷Ö%1F5ªÉ·½%2B¹Á>%14„tX27%1B%1BæÓ³šÅì%5EÐß0ÿþ÷…%04ËÛ³·æû÷›l%1Eÿªèk+¾ÍÜÔ%27O²Xª‚ØG››ø%15Ø9·%5CB%5D>Þ%24%7F¸%06>€·CùH%40r¡É»‡%2F_Ã°%5Eo>jÂ7%0F%3FîPËB%27é¦¢£¨€Ð­¹5ýþû%7C%3F%5D%26…n%1E4˜N%1AÆÞ%05pÅ+P%26™Í¼ïæ‡Óæ%2BPÙŽ0%3A_8Ô%60F%05˜ëQs¡Js%60-€ù+ëó%11%04Tïs+ùŠcËì%05¬%3BÃ©ó%03àT½Oí%1E«T%15âau%1A¸%16hè%15«%1DÑ’c„ÅÉ¶ka¡Ê%7BŸ%2Fm¿ÿþé¦Ú«)«ÛwÝùÔ÷…õ%5EM.ÛOžôjÁ¥ü8pòÛB%15¿H¨………›!Ý«%40%01%40ÝäAâ*%40%5D"¸Fí>™ëºïƒ%0Ea%0E%10¿æ%0FL‹%5DWùWŽˆ%7Czø%40*HëÄ´qA+Ì%01Ž6µ%03ÀÞq<ƒyëÄv†s®4¿O¬¼%5C±È­“%26%1B¤3ø*˜“>å×´×IƒÔ%1A%2BÙL%60»½À%1AµÌ%1EiÚ%10%02%1Cžžç„¶‘G+¼„ò%03ð«é7¨ºa—¥œ<Åï3Ð5‰ilÎ+˜ÁkÇ%25Rƒ%0E%23Ò30Æ%18†%1E—î”º0d%7DÐ+Öl-i%11J%1DtR+h%03%23%5D­¥%0E3%16ZìØ5%5EpªEã9G%10”nÎ%01Sfý%17%23I~á6Ì¬1—¬ÃÛñ%07ŒG¶jlŽ_¿ì%0ELSyÛ¦!%5DT‡!r¼¶rëF©Èê‘"4+n÷oK®çk¢2Í—¢è–%24%7BìÂ·L%105u7ìX¦%5E§>%60–%24Ë*Ê%11-%24%60%01‘BÄiyˆ¶%1E>†%02%06ˆEÍ4È§r’ó%04½d¾3%60Sö%40Ð%07ÍÉ¯«+X·L÷®ë%5D%0Ft±KÇ%3B¯GutBPÃ+—¸%2F³®VÏ»JMà%16ÒmÙrIL2Ô%06¡%03O‹f%5Cžk%15ëú®KaÉ¹ÞLW8%02®+J¥%1FÃqXu%1A‰r%24¨Ä*ae%3B-T%029+ÕuÐ%24AÝÖÐƒo±Lb%40Á+%3DtIVÉ”%08ÒÔB‚ŸÆ%02l"ÓA%26%02ŽIË%01÷aÑ%1AQ%01)+%3F®Ž²ä%0FÃ%26˜9¸Tx%3A–ÓÓ%5CÇ%07)á+%06ŽM(%16A«¥çx×%11f%10%3Abh%7Cë0´%1B¡éºs!ÒÌÀk%01SÁcù(%02¾‰âz0A%7C’MˆÄ’’Á§uòU®MÄ%0F<ÇîÅµ"k%5Eö%01V%1D‰%241ž%054%17˜%16%40wÂ+%40E6§H%5EVº%23Àþìv32€%24%19¦Ýu”¯¾£›Ô%12%5D¦¶!%0F+%3BX°f×dÆD%08UÂ%12%40Œð•‚%036èH9•Â¤+%25¹-š¸‡q8™‡%40ÙOQ›%5BB%2CBã4%5C%07%3AÔ“%7C¥€ªò%14!A%2C»%7DôÃg…­š%19u+fÚcÁ)nÍ›%17+%7B%2C‘›ÃyIoÊ<9‘Læç%16Mg%0F•æ“)¯%5C”1TÂc%3AL’SøWXç0ˆÒ%5CœMNOÄ%04+x„%06Qr%60ºUó%60•e%2C%039j™†¯+%05ñì-uÁ%16„o_ç+%11prJ+P+!ñ%03˜J%02Ø2·%14ìqoÎ%18gLgŽ%18·Átãsµ”ÐÏƒÎ.(‘+%12%19‡±pHfƒ%5C%1A¤%40Í~*k%127‹“KŸH»)Ô˜2P*AœÓº´+„pBIÑ–‡%19%2C%1D³0Óµ(˜€1%0E%1AW%2C%04ö%18ðÜ%1E²Ù¥o1+©Ò.AvÚ%40_%04+šÛÛ+ƒ-.ö†aE…ã´ªYÔ‘¢%1687p%06Zh)b2´†%5B%15÷%3A%1Aâ~2ÜE8pžcù%05Q~‰%3AZ·­£%06ßôs-Åòw%5B£%3AŠw%5BS>+¢vÄ%27¥+Ê•%60Ü%2CnÙD36%03¬n%17”åY²%2C+-i+M„É½%25É%7C¾KíÜ%06%05Ì%0FLPDyP·%5Cƒr²d¯.“šš*‚ÚÛë%1D%1EÄ%1E%15®dhhCû¹‰%11Ê6WD¦%2BÛÊ%1F¤+ÊOYñ¢èÖé+%2FO%5Bë2êÇéü%1C¹ÃcUc%1FÙ%195T%40®c©%0Fvˆ~þ!t%40YN%06o¼%0E¸Dj+e°V%7DX%10-Yh2ØØ%25ÌO-pƒ+TÌ¼%06v¨m%03I‰…’N‡Úr¤DºPA²ÒÌa¤iEÒb6¬!%24%10a%5Dý%19%19U%5D%07FÄƒaŽêÃ¥ÊÑ%03Ç‹ìïþ"OÇž5mh¤ŸéT>ùÝsá%7Dà_â*ðƒfp%1D4%5EõË%2BUBÆk‰‡§%06ŠtÏ´©%05VÈthD0”‚(Vs¹y‘Ë~Y%13¤ØþI"Î7%16%14>%17…%23–‘h¾ä+–%14ÌÄn¨˜§©*Î¨Ù1+×¶îb*´+§ÂTèšÅèF(e%13UÁ5É»¯fqT%15ÌóœDBõ%5B“XØz%24%15‰*%05Tƒ9®XMLqA%08%15KCÕqxp°§3òØc¾ë%40‹yDücÐ%2F%06%26%3AþÆÂÔ¨•…%03%11%25%24s~rN+™‘%5B%2C•—S–%13“_TÍâ%25§×n–ÒÚ%1C>U»Q*%06™î%18!XtRÀp%3AÞr×¹è´÷C%25p¸Ö+Ð‘Ç.½æÎçÇÀÀ%3A%3B%15%11‘›%27U1í%06Ï¢Fã%05%24>š0žsI%2CÚaBÖ%06´§%5BNh¤%5CƒÜoèRß¿%04œÜð)j%5B¡S³ß–ê%06×_%05îO%18%2F¨%3B–ã­“ÇÆRÇhc%18Å+šá±%3BK%3A¤2°‹µÅ%186OdŽrµ—Ü8ˆÀ©Žî%1AE<äHŒ%5B¬œÙ%25%2F¥%3A%2F%15zøòÞ%2CL‹v%26Ð¨ÍÝf+S%2CçŸŠ%10€H%08+›ÞfWbèGB¹%1E»øÿþ÷%7C÷%11Ÿ*wâÊ¹%5B%27NN%1FS×uL%5BÌ3±Þ%5CºzwE“%2Bèl¼%11J¿Ï%12!%0EQÚ%2F¥x"ýDÝ-Èå3à6–%7Džª%5DÞ>Ü¯·4ô%17‡·_%267¾gDK¡%15¯P7d%1A%08©_ÊfÈØÿM¢N%7D%11Ê%07£rK«¿œ½%1FA¥mz!ŒørØ‡”b%7B-Ò¸eÒXWÀ8«~Æ%0Eœ¾çg5pNÁ%3Alú8¯øª¥+•‹Œ€%13ã¡%25ºÙl+%19Þ’®ƒx%15CjpÆ%27¾Ä(%25ÍFI²‰½çø%1B·%1E5sÖ"!©ä%02%13FneÃ+øŽŠø%06BÉ¼%60ãÁÕUT…ËÊ×¼ÌDVŽX%5C²Ž‚‚)IrLŠc*ßÃŒ%1D%083v%1DÜÖ%1F‘ë%40(¹·3%1B7Â%5DT–ëLÈéª+àV%07f—%1B*~%7F‘(¤£È›d_±vàOç¥H÷‰Ô!%7CÅx%2CV˜LÛ%073Ô£%039%17…Æ–%2C‘%5DÇ²œËRºY%5EZBu%11%1D¥ýsÓTÛ%2CªVµÏ%23¯2%17ì§%5D%13Ï”“ZhÆÒ)þ¨yxŠ"ßË%24%2C+ÐpEÈß0é¥Ü‹+”ï%60Nù¤õ¬ß²žèD¶ñþ%16EÇ²FQ÷åÂŒg´%12ØF÷K.daWŒ.ÇÚE%5DP+XrÊ”Å%3BºGŠÁ+»¥L‘RÓµ¨k+áÊ+’XG÷K!ta·”(‘ï·%1Dïa.ð÷æú†K%3B‘Ë%3B“êExAìBà—‘Ä†(+ƒ¾“øêFmîI+%16¬r!š%1Aâìt¤%14¸µ®éùA%14Û%40âZS%2BsAaŒÒ*‚àŽŠ4ºñzÐòÈmÏ­´%0F8Ò%10¤w9°·(wr«Çç²%5Eñ%19y6Ñ%26²ƒ¾æt5%1C¼yÇ0%16f¥ÊÌV%1F%1BãÔåMêPƒ%2B%40%04~Êèšiœå5%26eÓ"3FÉnÄX%3A%15Ÿõ%18%40¡€ã¹PÞ2%11%07§yò4§%07ƒê%3B+%01ªõ%2Bp%1D%07„Ë+%08°4¡Ùê-Ö-¬ýA!‰%01è¨¾Øç(Y%7BÖ¿_%06%3A¿Ã%60B®“ÚZŠâöÊJ7!dôn%7Fb•àyMÿ¢GàßmBFcŽÉÇ%5B%23ò%05%3F¸ÀCWGÊ—ltÆV%12Ô99%021x%13¢ˆâj+xxÑ½J†d¸•%23%0EêämùÌ.%12hÔæNùÝ¸„kïæôË%04ûA³+%60É.Êø­Œ%5BGºN%1C…zë%1A“nÿ%02Îó%3B%08)û2ŽåÂ%18µ¯Æµ%3A¡ëgŠH®%5B»Óî6c6_Õ4%7D<ªnŠu3%2FTfxáHÎ5%269+µMz(rDáq%27%24ã4o²Ó˜£ÊEuªýÁÁ¦ï•+©%1B_ºt¿L6%1E%25FBí%15„Êí”Ñš•+W+%7D“’+ÁQÂˆrŠ)¹X%16+Fa%2B+%11%1BI%40Ù%13›Ã%08HQñ1G5‡0‘2¼÷+1%3B+9sú¨‹õ%02%23Gše<%3Ak+åCåšB³Ö‘¸%3DÇ%7B1ÏRm%15Ø%03J0%40%26+%2Co%60%04º%11R!%0FÏhC3O%15*%1B¢%1Bñù©%24£”¶%08d%03†ÄG¡Å¡X÷%0FTæX%1Ai“%3BéXÒŽ‰c+Ä2ˆQü>%3DËL+Ìœ<4ò¹%02Õ®ñ%18ºTHhs»µØn%25ÔŠý3+%3B%15Ÿ´ásS%19c%26%2F%5D‘Â%18¥¢%2CÒx%15Æ%7B%25%7CãVÈØ€šÖû)lëqErNÁâ%17%60QõÐnÑz5~pÇÞ¡0b%25%1De%08ÿñ·V”C%1C™%18ey§¶e%07+%1FÒ®*LªJ¥~%7BTäÖ¸“%5Bã¢¾29©«+Æ†0ßŸ%13¿%03%3A§èÆé°«´—%10å·%3Bâž%27ÙËÀd%0E®å¯%01%25%10e%0Ft©>€ÂC÷CáÊÑÑó"ÿ€%1AÓœ%0FSêÄ%7Byß%1A_2¦ÛZÉÊ•‰¶dn³§ãƒ¶­ß+%03.µ+§òÂ†%27%3D%3F%3D.®%7F%5C4Üˆp¦jÎÞ“h%7B%5ENÔ¦Û„QO%1B%40æú)ã¦§+t¾%5Då%23%3Bw¬-–ßŸ•%7B5B%60F%1Açôœ³%01yÅBV©’8¡*žÑ©%12ŸÚ>Î%13³K"þë7«ýV%15š%082²¿Tí%2FóÀÌ®s£+æ’á6É›º§j–Àt)Ÿ~Xj46%1E*Œöí÷ø†%07µÈ%0E¿Žì%1C%1F+®%2BuÓú%19+%5C%60ÀSÝ¿íUó%12%13¿ËZ~.yƒµúÂiæ!9‚ïí”+%26¾Œÿ+þçÏ‚Ê%3FøÖØ–òìçÝÖ%06Ò²çá%3B¢â%19­ò5o%3D¬%7FKž>z»³»%7D²ý–Àâƒ%40™%07%17OùJ%05V%23%7F¡ìÌ%3Feø%0E‹%7F%1A½%3AXY¯à³m•jÅôOa9+%7B§%03à%5EH%16O.V%2B†sÉ_s9…ê%19%60%05ü+¶e•%5D±ê™_unÕuƒjÐûXýhºÕ%2BËGtv%07%05Ô)¾ð‡%05+©ï+Øi¹GcñµW¤ð4®"%12NÞ-ùj%2C”ò%5C½æöÝïIöiÛKër+q%17V°¼j•lQ%7D©*Uá¨%60¨q+õ-’z²Øï%3B%5E€_ÕÎãÍº°B×ÖlÃZÖº%13½%0FŒ½ûw%07¯Ä6Ê“Ì‡D%14ª7k%3Aÿô%1DH·M%2CûM%7Bû›Ö>ü_€%01rÆ>%1BÌ¹%17%3AáË“%26%5EÆ%40%3F5+6å0<üÛøÇ™%2F%1AµXÔ!¶¹úV‰RÂ©âGN—*“¼Q%5D+¼‘~£ºT™æ%14eZS”1%27kŠÙœ+¼•%02W%1E%25S%1Eó0%07%3D°§ðM6ÿSô%06%19>Üu%13©ƒO¥Vˆ%06%1Eíàa¨®JsKÄ%1EiÍ%25aÈT%19ã%1F%25ß(eÕÀ%2C™%12E£+%15—<ƒÆãn6Db%14E*¤¢â%03%03ˆ%1BÀHP%5Coˆ%231Üæ%5E%27H"~•oEáR’â(5%3A·"“ù³jæGþVY%1C%5B%24š%08í“Ïª5eë%1E>xË_¬%16î%02Œ%12ÀçÝß%23U%0EèµfT5°ì…é›%1DÓâ+%7D°“™-%5B%03’írÀR%05šÙ%02ü3vIÒ~%1EóŒ%2B%11·+¤%0F%3Fy+Bñ-%05+%0Fš+%0F%13Ž½%7CÂM%24%16%01%13“¿%7CTÍÏ%1Bôò3ð…%3B~%05AÂ%26ë%04Ÿ%11–%7D%25ŠøŒ%3Fû%27ƒ%1A%10Ôu%7C%13“Ö+%7FÌÂ¼ÀF+%0FkLiŸ%5E0QQb%12ó%1E¼%60%1E+ýe¦‹+Ë­„%17«ãS±%17ÅT%7FÔøƒàb%14%13vå%1D¤–%1EfÚL‡åã%07ŒÐý¢%7F%237+úW6¸¹-89îqY¹´ù•%16U’Ì2«§5É%27"%3D2«µ¶úóÍ%06‘%0E+%04º•%407—kËÉÏJ%1Et%3Bn-å%01%2C%26ívm%5CåK+ôbslåË+ôR%23%0F%60E%01X%1D%5Bùj%02½<¾åk+ôJnË›+¥ßÇ7½©+ÓÚø¶7ÕqjD­Oüró*ƒµ%16Ý«…O1+.
```

Comment: provide error logs, console errors, `htaccess` file. and constants( 'DB_CHARSET', 'DB_COLLATE' ) from `wp-config.php` file

Comment: Chek the site https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAkOydDHOU0HKu9vUl0N_k54mTuSrnzwarNWWgnucBtXw/12/109069468/png/32x32/3/1517270400/0/2/Captura%20de%20tela%202018-01-29%2016.27.17.png/EJXsrFQYqi4gAigC/bswxc4vevXV4vVtTv3EzfRpf3CvAeHf--Cg5OYLneAQ?dl=0&preserve_transparency=1&size=1280x960&size_mode=3

Comment: I just installed a plugin to save errors. /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

Comment: without any plugin you can check errors. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001 . and provide errors, if you got them. also, check developers console of browser, and provide errors, if they exists