# Endriod/QrCode library with wordpress. ( internal server error 500)

Tags: php, wordpress, qr-code

i have tried to use Endroid/QrCode library but when i insert the code to my custom template page gives me an internal server error 500 and displays a blank white page.

```
include WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/qrcode/src/QrCode.php';

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qr = new QrCode();

 $qr -> setText("Llalala")
     -> setSize(200)
     -> render();
```

If i comment out this line `$qr = new QrCode();` than my page will load. Thank you in advance.

Comment: enable debug mode of wordpress and provide error logs to us: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001

Comment: its enabled but there is nothing to show. its empty.

Comment: it's strange, because when you got 500 errors, the main reason for it is fatal errors. did the code you provided added to wp files? also, check server errors log, when getting 500 error. there must be some errors