# Trying to make a local copy of an existing wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp

I'm using WAMP to try and make a local copy of a rather large wordpress site.
After some struggle with the database i moved all the files from the ftp: to my www/ wamp folder.

Now when i try to open the pages i get:

*localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500*

BUT i can open my localhost/wp-admin and see my wordpress dashboard.

Comment: you may have some fatal errors. enable debug mode on, and provide error logs, also, look at apache errors. then provide all errors you got. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001

Comment: With WAMPServer you should never change the `\wamp\www` folder. Always place your code either in a sub folder `wamp\www\project` or a folder outside wampserver like `C:\websrc\project\www` and create a Virtual Host for each project

Comment: This is specially necessary when using WordPress.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replay i did put it in wamp/www/project, sry for making it confusing. 
I tried creating a Virtual Host for the project and still the same.

Comment: Did you read and apply all these suggestions on the [Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) related to moving a WP site?

Comment: I did not, i have been going over it to see if it fixes my problem. 
It seems that the theme is not working on the local version now...

Answer (score -1):

Generally, it can happen for many reasons but you can debug it step by step!

1. Check .htaccess file.

Delete this file or replace it with a fresh one!
Some plugins like wp-cache alters .htaccess file to achieve its purpose. So updating this file may solve your problem.

2. Update Permalinks to default from WordPress settings.
3. Replace all WordPress files with fresh WordPress files except wp-content folder. you need to update database again.
4. Set another theme and check if works and again set your default theme. Sometimes theme also causes this error!

Comment: It was the theme that's not working properly thanks!