# TagDiv Composer plugin causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress project I use this theme "*Newspaper*". This theme allows me to use plugin "*TagDiv Composer*". Every time I activate this plugin I get **500 Internal Server Error**.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at lorem@ipsum.lorum.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I can see my website online without any problem, but I can't access wp-admin. If I deactivate this specific plugin everything is back to normal.

I have tried to deactivate all the plugins and activate them again, increase the memory from 64M to 128M, update the wordpress version to the latest. Finally I tried the same theme with the same plugin in another Wordpress project and I didn't have any problem (at least till now).

Any ideas or any help would be very helpful!

Comment: first of all, activate debug mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001 , https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress , after it provide us debug log

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide on the developer forums: https://forum.tagdiv.com/system-status-parameters-guide/ Such issues usually mean wrong memory allocation. You can also contact the theme author to get support.