# WordPress - Your session has expired after I publish post

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I am facing very strange issue since yesterday, I have created a website and have used various custom fields for a POST type.

Issue:-

Custom values fields is a loop (CFS Plugin) and when I am adding a new values and update then it shows white death screen and says **Your session has expired**

Also when I am updating without giving any new value then it is loading back with a success message "Post Updated'

I am not able to figure out, please help.

I have already increased all the LIMIT to this but this did not helped.

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

Thanks Sanny

Comment: first, enable [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001), then, provide error logs

Comment: just one unrelated notice I got after doing what you said - [05-Apr-2018 08:58:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/semant/page-templates/login.php on line 82

Comment: think, that it's related notice. change theme to default one( such as twentyseventeen ), and try to make same steps.

Comment: with default theme, it is behaving the same..!! :(

Comment: deactivate all plugins besides CFS plugin and try same steps( add some custom fields )

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result!!

Comment: provide list and versions of all active plugins/theme/wordpress