# Wordpress new added multiple site not working

Tags: wordpress

I have used wordpress multiple sites in my server, but recently I have changed server to new server. After changed new one, I can create new sites, but I cant login into the new site dashboard. It gives blank page issue. After tried to refresh one or more time I have faced HTTP 500 error.

I have checked with my htacess. Its not working

Comment: first, [enable debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001), then provide us error logs

Comment: also, what you mean with `I have checked with my htacess. Its not working`? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

First of all set "wp_debug" to true in wp-config.php. It will show the error. Also set `error_reporting(1)` in top of wp-config.php.

Secondly, open your .htaccess file and make it empty.

Now try to open your dashboard.