# Getting Internal Server Error 500 when trying to access product category

Tags: wordpress

When I go here: https://www.allveterans.com/costs-services/ and click on any item appearing underneath "URNS & SERVICE ITEMS" heading, it is redirecting me to an Internal Error Page.

Can anyone help me out to fix this?

Comment: Find the server logs and check what is the exact error that you get. Then find the related file that causes the issue. Update your question with the error log and the part of the code that creates it. Only then we can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocomerce checkout page internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854995/woocomerce-checkout-page-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 0):

That happens to us too.  First you need to troubleshoot where the error is and then fix the error.
(1) To Troubleshoot, if you have FTP access, then edit your wp-config file, change a line near the bottom:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to be

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

(2) Then recreate the issue.  Your Wordpress will show you what line of code is creating the issue.  Then come back and re-ask... somebody here should be able to help from here.

p.s. - don't forget to change it back when you get your error code!