# Images not showing error after WordPress migration from localhost to live server

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded my website to my server.

But when I call the website, it shows the url "localhost:8888", and gives me an error:

- Some images broken
- Some parts don't functions properly.

the website link is: [www.smarts-co.com](http://www.smarts-co.com)

in `wp_options` table, I did changed the `home` & `siteurl`  values in MySQL to my site URL, but still getting the error that you get when you click on my website.

[image]

Comment: Chances are you need to do this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: I did that , but still no working , I've attached an image to clarify that .

Comment: You may want to go to settings->permalinks and then just click save to flush them. You also may want to use a search and replace plugin on the database to make sure there aren't references to your local environment.

Comment: I think this is also another issue , I can't login into my wp-admin to do that , it also gives me an error @git-e-up

Comment: Do you have managed hosting? You may want to talk to your hosting provider if that's the case.

Comment: @git-e-up Actually I managed to login into wp-admin, and I did your comment but no luck

Comment: Well, I don't have any other suggestions, except perhaps to look at your code (php and js) for something that may be directing back to your local.

Comment: are you sure, you made changes in the right db? do you enabled [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856127/8053001)? any errors? do you tried to find all occurance in the db? do you have any active cache/permofance/security plugins? do you wrote some code related to `.htaccess`? do you checked `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @Mimma , Would you please update: 1- How you uploaded from localhost to server? 2- Screenshot about error as later on after fix; it won't be visible by providing the site URL. 3- Try to improve your question and subject line so its useful by time to all readers and not your specific error situation. Also it will be useful to comment in the answer you picked that part exactly fixed the issue. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly you need to properly move WordPress to Live Server.

Try to right click on your site's logo and open image in new tap:
You will get the following link:

```
http://localhost:8888/smartService/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-website-1.png
```

This means you didn't migrate the site properly.

the short answer is you need to fix the URLs in your site as per images issues and some more work if any additional bug.

The above link should look like:

```
http://smarts-co.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-website-1.png
```

I would do the following to migrate site from localhost to live server:

**Method 1:**

Use some plugins to migrate WordPress site, pickup your favorite from Plugins directory.

**Method 2:**

Its manual but I like it and mostly never fail; you need to know what you are doing though if you tried this method.

1. Upload files to server.
2. Using Notepad++, find and replace all http://localhost/ to http://www.example.com/
3. You need offcourse to fix wp-config.php

**Method 3:**

You can try some find/replace plugin to search MySQL and fix the issue.
I believe you may want to try method 3 as you already uploaded to server from local host.

Also please google:  (*how to upload wordpress website from localhost to cpanel*)

*Note: this answer is realated to fixing images not showing after uploading to live server and not a complete manual for migration.*

Comment: Would you please tell which method helped you and what exactly fixes your problem; so we all can learn and I would recommend improving your question's subject line for better google indexing.. it now looks generic.

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php, try adding this code above `// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.smarts-co.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.smarts-co.com');
```

BTW, your website seems to be loading; your logo picture needs to be fixed though.